# Blender file opening as new file

Tags: blend-files

My computer crashed while I was working just a little while ago and now my Blender file will not open properly. It hangs a while before opening as if it is a completely new .blend file (cube, camera, light). This is a 200mb file with a ton of stuff in it, is there any way to open it up?

Add'l info: I can't link or append the file either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computer Crashed - entire scene replaced with Default Cube](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58027/computer-crashed-entire-scene-replaced-with-default-cube)

Answer (score 1):

Solved: File -> Recover -> Autosave